# $t$-balanced numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems, prime-constellations

Disclaimer: throughout this question, we'll assume the truth of Goldbach's conjecture.

For $n$ a large enough composite positive integer, write $r_{0}(n):=\inf\{r>0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$, $r_{0}^{-}(n):=n-\sup\{p\mid p<n\}$, $r_{0}^{+}(n)=\inf\{p\mid p>n\}-n$, $r_{k+1}^{-}(n)=n-\sup\{p\mid p<n-r_{k}^{-}(n)\}$, $r_{k+1}^{+}(n)=\inf\{p\mid p>n+r_{k}^{+}(n)\}-n$.

Let $t_{\pm}(n):=\inf\{k\mid r_{k}^{\pm}(n)=r_{0}(n)\}$. Write also $k_{0}(n):=\pi(n+r_{0}(n))-\pi(n-r_{0}(n))$. One has $t_{-}(n)+t_{+}(n)=k_{0}(n)-1$.

Say $n$ is $t$-balanced iff $t_{-}(n)=t_{+}(n)=t$. Can one get an asymptotics for the number of $t$-balanced integers not exceeding $x$?

Comment: Is $t_{-}(n)$ just the number of primes in the open interval $(n-r_0(n),n)$?

Comment: Indeed, that's a way to phrase it.